# c# console application returning no results

Tags: restsharp

This code runs fine in my windows form application using .net framework 4.6.2 but when I go to make it a console application so it can be ran from the task scheduler I get no results. I think I am losing something in translation.

```
        RestClient restClient = new RestClient("https://api.vault.com");
        string refreshToken = @"abc";
        string encodedClientIdSecret = Base64Encode("AP-123");

        string responseStr = "";
        string url = "/v1/OAuth";
        dynamic jsonObj = "";

        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(url, Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", encodedClientIdSecret);

        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "refresh_token");
        request.AddParameter("refresh_token", refreshToken);

        IRestResponse response;
        restClient.Execute(request);

        response = restClient.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content + " || " + encodedClientIdSecret);
        Console.ReadKey();

        jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);

        responseStr = jsonObj.access_token;

        return responseStr;
```

It basically tells me the value cannot be null, and when I look at response.Content I get nothing and the status code comes back as "0". Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added:

```
        //Required For SSL/TLS Error Start
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        //Required For SSL/TLS Error End
```

and I got my results. Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Excuse me, could you let me know where you added above code?